# Ubuntu 13.04 with LVM+FDE: "Failed to load config file /etc/lvm/lvm.conf" (doesn't boot with new kernel)

Tags: boot, 13.04, kernel, encryption

I recently set up Ubuntu 13.04 amd64 and checked the box for full disk encryption at the installation.

It worked fine, but yesterday Ubuntu ran an update and now with the new kernel (3.8.0-29-generic) my system doesn't boot any longer (with the old in it still works). It says the following:

"There appears to be one or more degraded LVM volumes, and your root device may depend on the LVM volumes being online. One or more of the following LVM volumes are degraded: Parse error at byte 611 (line 21): unexpected token Failed to load config file /etc/lvm/lvm.conf Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems: - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline) - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?) - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!"

Comment: Try to boot on the older kernel and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Thomas - you appear to have multiple accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your accounts are merged. Once done, you'll be able to edit your question with further information.

Comment: **Thomas:** You may need to register an account before using the *contact us* link to request your unregistered accounts be merged with your registered ones (as @fossfreedom says).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I am the one to blame.

I had put `issue_discards` in my `lvm.conf` some days ago to enable TRIM support for the LVM layer.

Actually I should have put `issue_discards=1` in there to achieve this.

So I booted the old kernel, changed `lvm.conf` and ran `sudo update-initramfs -u`. Now I am able to also boot the new one.

Thank you Salem for your reply. It brought on me on the right track.